# Javascript isnt running well

Tags: javascript

I'm following a course where we're building a color game. I followed step by step everything, still my code isn't working at some point.

```js
let colors = [
  "rgb(255, 0, 0)",
  "rgb(255, 255, 0)",
  "rgb(0, 255, 0)",
  "rgb(0, 255, 255)",
  "rgb(0, 0, 255)",
  "rgb(255, 0, 255)"
];

let squares = document.querySelectorAll('.square');

for (let i = 0; i < squares.length; i++) {
  squares[i].style.backgroundColor = colors[i];
}
```

```css
body {
    background-color: #232323;
}

.square {
    width: 30%;
    background: purple;
    padding-bottom: 30%;
    float: left;
    margin: 1.66%;
}

#container {
    max-width: 600px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
h1 {
    color: white;
}
```

```html
<h1>The Great RGB Color Game</h1>

<div id='container'>
  <div class='square'></div>
  <div class='square'></div>
  <div class='square'></div>
  <div class='square'></div>
  <div class='square'></div>
  <div class='square'></div>
</div>
```

Problem is that my squares aren't changing to the color i passed them in javascript, and i can't figure why, even by inspecting and so on... Anything i missed?

Comment: The question's been answered already, but I'd like to point out that in cases like this, your browser's *Inspect* or *Inspect Element* tool is extremely helpful! You can see that your squares certainly do have the style applied, so the JavaScript is fine. Hovering the element in code while inspecting will reveal `0 x 0`-sized `<div>`s.

Comment: Thx for answering. I edited my post, and my squares do have a size (i provided css). Still not worcking and i can't figure out why =/

Comment: @Payo As you can see when you run your snippet the code you provided works fine. Please provide a reproducable example.

Comment: I added ```window.onload = function() { mycode} ``` and it solved my problem, though i dont really know why !

Comment: @Peyo In that case you placed your script before your html code. So the script ran before the html elements where parsed.

Answer (score 2):

Your square div's dont have a size. Your code works perfectly just give them content or a size with css.

```js
let colors = [
  "rgb(255, 0, 0)",
  "rgb(255, 255, 0)",
  "rgb(0, 255, 0)",
  "rgb(0, 255, 255)",
  "rgb(0, 0, 255)",
  "rgb(255, 0, 255)"
];

let squares = document.querySelectorAll('.square');

for (let i = 0; i < squares.length; i++) {
  squares[i].style.backgroundColor = colors[i];
}
```

```html
<h1>The Great RGB Color Game</h1>

<div id='container'>
  <div class='square'>1</div>
  <div class='square'>2</div>
  <div class='square'>3</div>
  <div class='square'>4</div>
  <div class='square'>5</div>
  <div class='square'>6</div>
</div>
```

Comment: My squares do have sizeds, i just didnt show the CSS, but they have a size and even a base color which is purple. I edited my post to add css.

Answer (score 2):

You need to specify a size for your squares or fill them with content.

```js
let colors = [
  "rgb(255, 0, 0)",
  "rgb(255, 255, 0)",
  "rgb(0, 255, 0)",
  "rgb(0, 255, 255)",
  "rgb(0, 0, 255)",
  "rgb(255, 0, 255)"
];

let squares = document.querySelectorAll('.square');

for (let i = 0; i < squares.length; i++) {
  squares[i].style.backgroundColor = colors[i];
}
```

```css
.square { display: inline-block; width: 2em; height: 2em; }
```

```html
<h1>The Great RGB Color Game</h1>

<div id="container">
  <div class="square"></div>
  <div class="square"></div>
  <div class="square"></div>
  <div class="square"></div>
  <div class="square"></div>
  <div class="square"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: My squares do have sizes, i just didnt show the CSS, but they have a size and even a base color which is purple. I edited my post to add the css.

Comment: @Peyo Then what's your question?